# What was the origin of sigils as an alternative to explicit type declarations?

Tags: basic, shell

Dartmouth BASIC seems to have gotten strings around 1968, and BASIC uses the `$` on variable names to indicate that they're strings. This is a strategy for avoiding the need for explicit type declarations. I imagine that type declarations would have been considered an unwanted barrier to user-friendliness, and they would have also been a a poor fit because the language lacked any syntax at levels broader than the level of one statement (no begin-end, etc.). (Most implementations after Dartmouth BASIC were pure statement-by-statement interpreters.)

The first Unix shell came out in 1971. The Bourne shell uses a similar (but prefixed) `$` syntax, although it has more to do with dereferencing and string interpolation. Perl, which is basically shell on steroids, uses the sigils `$`, `@`, and `%` in a manner similar to Dartmouth BASIC's, as an alternative to explicit typing (although the distinction being made is a different one, and they are also used for string interpolation).

Was the use of sigils as an alternative to type declarations an innovation of Dartmouth BASIC, or was it present in some earlier system such as the Multics shell (which I believe inspired the Bourne shell)?

Comment: BASIC was designed to allow lines of source to be processed without any semantic dependency upon any lines in the source code that have not been executed, nor any syntactic dependency upon other lines whether they have been executed or not.  I don't know if it was the first such language, but those aspects somewhat force the design.

Comment: What supercat said for sure, plus, _compatability with earlier versions of BASIC_. There just weren't that many types.  In fact, for the first THREE VERSIONS of Dartmouth BASIC there was only ONE type: float.  String _variables_ weren't introduced until version 4 (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC)).  So, when introducing string variables, in addition to wanting to minimize implementation effort, you also wanted _all old programs of your students and professors to keep working_.  So it would have been hard to _introduce_ types.

Comment: It's kind of interesting, BTW, how _limited_ Dartmouth BASIC was initially - yet, it was useful and popular enough that the experiment of creating it continued!  Note that (according to that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC) article) it didn't even have an _interactive_ mode of execution until v3!!  (No "Enter 1 for YES, 2 for No" or even "Enter 1 to continue, 0 to stop" until then!)

Comment: Finally, the era of the introduction of BASIC was the era of assembly languages, LISP, RPG, COBOL, and FORTRAN.  You don't see any type declarations in any of those.  (Well, COBOL.  But _that_ clearly wasn't going to influence any academically-designed language used for students.)

Comment: @supercat The lines have a dependency on the values of variables mentioned in them, though, and you could store the declared type in the same table. Or just have untyped variables and typed values, like Lisp. Maybe it just saves a bit of space to store variables of different types in separate linked lists.

Comment: @benrg: The question of whether `150 IF X < Y THEN 200` should perform a numeric comparison or a string comparison should not require examining anything else in the code, and should not be affected by anything else the program has done.

Comment: @supercat: I don't understand your first comment, for the reasons benrg gave. I don't understand your second comment, since I don't understand where the "should" comes from.

Comment: Is a trailing dollar sign significantly different to an initial I, J, K, L, M, or N?  It doesn't seem that way to me, it's just dividing up the available-identifier space.  The only difference (as hinted above) is that FORTRAN did the partitioning before there were users concerned about compatibility, and BASIC did it afterwards.

Comment: @another-dave It is because the trailing $ is not part of the name but a leading letter is and that is especially important when you've only got two characters for each name (and the second character has to be a number).

Comment: @davidbak Why not write up your comments into an answer?

Comment: @JeremyP - in BASIC, sure, but not in general.  I'm suggesting that FORTRAN had a 'sigil prefix' rather than a 'sigil suffix'.

Comment: @davidbak - "you don't see any type declarations".  And, in most languages then, to the extent possible, you don't see any variable declarations, type or otherwise.  Sometimes you need to specify array size, though BASIC defaulted to 11 elements.  FORTRAN allowed you to control storage allocation (COMMON and EQUIVALENCE) but that's a little different to declaring a variable.  ALGOL was an outlier in that every variable had to be explicitly declared, and as I recall reading, that idea was not 100% popular.  Mostly, the early languages allowed you to introduce identifiers just by using them.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I don't know if the first BASIC implementations reserved space to hold a value for every possible variable name, but they could certainly have had an array of 286 slots, each of which kept track of whether a variable was used and, if so, where it lived.  When a BASIC interpreter received a line like "30 A1=B+C", it could scan that and convert it to an operation sequence "load variable 1; load variable 2; add them.  Store the result to variable 52", without having to know anything about any other part of the program, since A1 would always be variable #52.

Comment: @BenCrowell: If the code had been "B2=C(I)", that could have been handled as "load variable 9; read that element of array 2; store that into variable #79".  The presence of parentheses after "C" would have indicated that it was an array, whether or not the compiler knew of any "DIM" statement for it.  If the book "A Basic Approach to BASIC" described Dartmouth BASIC as well as HP Basic (I used the latter) strings were a weird hybrid, since their names could be used with and without parentheses.  "PRINT A$" would print all of A$, but IIRC "PRINT A$(4)" would print the fourth character.

Comment: @supercat - that's HP BASIC.  DTSS had arrays of strings, so A$(4) is the 5th string.  (0-based, as with numeric arrays).  Hmm, I think perhaps I learned on HP BASIC - specifically it was dialup to the [Open University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_University), my maths teacher was doing a CS degree with the OU.

Comment: @another-dave: For some reason I'd thought HP-BASIC was derived from Dartmouth BASIC.  Was the way HP-BASIC handles strings unique to that dialect when it was produced (I know Atari BASIC behaved likewise, but that came later).

Comment: @supercat - maybe the 'derivation' happened before the 4th edition of Dartmouth BASIC?

Answer (score 2):

> I imagine that type declarations would have been considered an unwanted barrier to user-friendliness

Not necessarily, as for example arrays do have a `DIM`.

> Perl, which is basically shell on steroids, uses the sigils $, @, and % in a manner similar to Dartmouth BASIC's

Not really: In Perl, the prefixes and the context determine the **usage**. Example from the tutorial:

```
my %fruit_color = ("apple", "red", "banana", "yellow");
$fruit_color{"apple"};           # gives "red"
```

In BASIC, using different sigils means those are always different variables.

In Perl, can also evaluate the same variable in a string or list context:

```
my @animals = ("camel", "llama", "owl");
if (@animals < 5) { ... }
```

Which you cannot do in BASIC.

Which brings me to the main point:

> Was the use of sigils as an alternative to type declarations an innovation

An **important point** that has not been brought up is that in quite a few early BASIC dialects (and unlike e.g. PERL), only the first letter and the following number counts. However, the sigil **also** counts. Which meant now you could have `A` for a number, `A$` for a string, and `A()` for an array, and they would all be different. This made programming a lot easier.

And this approach is older than BASIC, and also used in other languages like [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) (where a following `^` distinguishes scalars and so called "globals" that are tree-structured).

> The Bourne shell uses a similar (but prefixed) $ syntax, although it has more to do with dereferencing and string interpolation.

Exactly. So the way unix shells (and languages like [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl)) use a leading `$` is quite different.

Comment: DIM is only actually needed for arrays whose largest index exceeds 10. I regard that as evidence of avoiding type declarations where possible, with a dollop of pragmatism on the side.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @BenCrowell your question is based on some assumptions that don't really apply, in particular that use of `$` of BASIC in the one hand and shells or Perl on the other hand is somehow comparable. It does explain why BASIC uses `$` and `()` as suffixes to create new kinds of variables, and that this is not a new idea, and has been used before.

Comment: Your facts about Perl are wrong, and you also got the name of the language wrong.